# Javascript Split method

Tags: javascript

```
var string = abc123;
string.split(*POSITION=3)???
```

Is there a way to split this string into an array of strings that is `[abc,123]`?
Is the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method the right thing to use?

Comment: split() needs a delimiter to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the `split` method is *not* the right thing to use here, as its purpose is to segment a string based on a certain *character*.

You could certainly write your own function, of course:

```
function partition(str, index) {
  return [str.substring(0, index), str.substring(index)];
}

// results in ["123", "abc"]
var parts = partition("123abc", 3);
```

If you wanted to write `"123abc".partition(3)` instead, you could make that possible by extending `String.prototype`:

```
String.prototype.partition = function(index) {
  return [this.substring(0, index), this.substring(index)];
};
```

Personally, though, I'd recommend avoiding that sort of tomfoolery (search the web for "extending built-in objects in JavaScript" if you want to read what others have to say on the topic).

Comment: Just curious (because I see this time to time), if you don't recommend doing it by extending the prototype, why not do it in the way you do recommend?  e.g.:  function partionString(str, index) {...

Comment: I highly doubt this is what the OP wants... `"hello friend".partition(3)
["hel", "lo friend"]` doesn't split `*POSITION=3` at all for me. Then again, `*POSITION=3` is very open to interpretation :D Just putting it out there.

Comment: @rob: Totally fair point; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Esailija: It certainly is open to interpretation... I see, *your* interpretation was that he wants to split the string up into an arbitrary number of segments of equal *length*? My answer reflects what *I* think he wants: to cut a string in two parts around a specified position. But you're right; it's very possible I've misconstrued the OP's intent.

Comment: @DanTao, I mean like if you have a string `"FFFFFF"` and then do `*POSITION=2` split, you will end up with `["FF", "FF", "FF"]` (Split every 2 characters), which is the kind of functionality php [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) does. But looks like he wasn't looking for that after all :P

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, I realized what your interpretation was after noticing your answer. Anyway, goes to show the importance of expressing requirements clearly (when possible)!

Comment: var setup = "this is a test".match(/..?.?/g);  - you could make this a function by generating the appropriate amount of ".?" after the first "."

Comment: @Tracker1: But I think we've already confirmed this is not the behavior the OP was looking for. He wanted to split a string into two parts around a specified position.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a simple `RegExp` match?

```
var arr = "abc123".match(/^([a-z]+)(\d+)$/i);
arr.shift();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = "this is a test".match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

No but it is trivial to implement that:

```
function splitn( str, n ){
var r = [], offset = 0, l = str.length;

    while( offset < l ) {
    r.push( str.substr( offset, n ) );
    offset += n;
    }
return r;
}
```

Then:

```
var string = "abc123";
console.log( splitn( string, 3 ) );
//["abc", "123"]
```

Assuming you want similar functionality to [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)